# PowerShell to fetch string from webpage

Tags: html, powershell

I am trying to navigate to URL example.com and trying to fetch the string to validate it.

Below is the code:

```
$ie = New-Object -Com InternetExplorer.Application;
$ie.Visible = $true;
$ie.Navigate("example.com");
```

After navigating to this site I need to fetch string from web page, i.e "enabled:true".

Below is the HTML code:

```html
<tr class="prop" name="enabled">
              <td valign="top" class="name">
                <a href="/JSPWiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Enabled" target="_blank">Enabled</a>:
              </td>

                <td valign="top" class="value" style="WORD-BREAK:BREAK-ALL;">true</td>
```

Example image:

[image: example image]

Comment: Why don't you use [Invoke-Webrequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-5.1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, wait until the document has finished loading:

```
while ($ie.Busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 200 }
```

Once the page is loaded you can access its elements via the DOM tree. For properly written pages you'd access the elements by their ID, but in your case the author seems to have used the `name` attribute or no identifier at all, so you'll have to select the parent object by name first:

```
$row = $ie.Document.GetElementsByName('enabled') |
       Select-Object -First 1
```

then get the inner text from the nested `<td>` elements:

```
$row.GetElementsByTagName('td') | Select-Object -Expand innerText
```